# How to write a function that adds a list to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

busy coders on this wonderful community.

I was trying to completing a task from a book called "Automate the Boring Stuff". And here, I'm trying to append this dragonLoot[] list to the itemsSatchel{} dictionary. I tried to use this update attribute, after I changed the List to a Dictionary, but it failed, so I really don't know what to do about it. HELP!

```
import pprint

itemsSatchel = {'Arrow': 12,
                'Gold Coin': 42,
                'Rope': 1,
                'Torch': 6,
                'Dagger':1}

dragonLoot = ['Gold Coin',
              'Gold Coin'
              'Dagger'
              'Gold Coin',
              'Ruby']

def addToSatchel(self):
    #This part is my pain in the ___#


def displaySatchel(self):
    print("Inventory: ")
    itemsCounter = 0
    for k,v in itemsSatchel.items() :
        pprint.pprint(str(v) + ' ' + str(k))
        itemsCounter += v
    print('Total number of items: ' + str(itemsCounter))

addToSatchel({dragonLoot})

displaySatchel(itemsSatchel)
```

Comment: When you name an argument named `self`, this implies the use of a `class`. However, you do not need to do that. This an be solved without classes.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: So itemsSatchel should end up with gold coins == 45, daggers == 2 and ruby == 1 ?

Comment: @Leonid Thank you, I didn't know about the classes. This helps a lot!

Comment: @DirtyBit Thanks, I want my output be exactly like Jon Clements mentioned about.

Comment: @JonClements Wow, that is just what I wanted!

Comment: @pistol2myhead Thanks, I want my output be exactly like Jon Clements mentioned about.

Comment: @TimDai note that you're missing a trailing `,` after `Gold Coin` and `Dagger` and Python concatenates adjacent string literals, so you've got 3 items there, one of them called `Gold CoinDaggerGold Coin`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also consider the use of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here. It can be initialized or *updated* from a `dict` or a list of items.

```
from collections import Counter

itemsSatchel = Counter({'Arrow': 12,
                        'Gold Coin': 42,
                        'Rope': 1,
                        'Torch': 6,
                        'Dagger':1})

dragonLoot = ['Gold Coin', ...]

def addToSatchel(items):
    itemsSatchel.update(items)

addToSatchel(dragonLoot)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the "self" arguments, this is not a class methods, rather that a functionality programming.
Now, if I understand you right, you may trying to do something like:

```
def addToSatchel():
    for el in dragonLoot:
        itemsSatchel[el] = itemsSatche.setdefault(el, 0) + 1    

def displaySatchel():
    ...
    ...
```

calls should be:

```
addToSatchel()
displaySatchel()
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. But for my understanding, this would not be functioning if I add some more lists to the dictionary. How can I amend this function if there are a few more lists to be added?

Answer (score 0):

Try to go through the elements in your array and increment the value of the same element in the dictionary by 1 if it exists there, or just set 1 if it isn't there.

like so:

```
# Hello World program in Python
import pprint

itemsSatchel = {'Arrow': 12,
                'Gold Coin': 42,
                'Rope': 1,
                'Torch': 6,
                'Dagger':1}

dragonLoot = ['Gold Coin',
              'Gold Coin',
              'Dagger',
              'Gold Coin',
              'Ruby']

def addToSatchel():
    for item in dragonLoot:
        if item in itemsSatchel:
            itemsSatchel[item] += 1
        else:
            itemsSatchel[item] = 1 

def displaySatchel():
    print("Inventory: ")
    itemsCounter = 0
    for k,v in itemsSatchel.items() :
        pprint.pprint(str(v) + ' ' + str(k))
        itemsCounter += v
    print('Total number of items: ' + str(itemsCounter))

addToSatchel()

displaySatchel()
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! It was perfect! I still have a long way to go but it doesn't seems so long with you guys' help!